# First Year ODE Exam Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> What are the eigenfunctions that satisfy
>   $$xy''(x) + (1-x)y'(x) + y(x) = -\lambda y(x)$$
>   on the interval $I = [0, \infty)$ given that the eigenvalues are natural numbers (positive integers) such that $y(0) = 1$?

This question was on my first-year university ODE final exam and not a single student was able to solve it. We are trying to have it curved from the final exam grade, do we have a strong case or is this fairly "ordinary" material?

Comment: This is known as the [Laguerre ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials).  If $1+\lambda$ is a non-negative integer, the solutions are called Laguerre polynomials.

Comment: Please use mathjax instead of images next time, and avoid clickbaity titles: [MathJax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @lulu that is very helpful thank you. Is this typically learned in first year Ordinary Differential Equations courses? The students in my class are trying to make a case to curve the exam grades by having this question removed.

Comment: @FrankVel will do thank you for your help!

Comment: That very much depends on the course.  It's a fairly standard example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, if you have encountered this as a Freshman, you are supposed find the solution as a *power series*. Quite generally when you have a differential equation of the form
$$
N(x) y'' + M(x)y'+P(x)y=0
$$
with $N,M,P$ polynomials, and $N(x)$ with no roots in the *interior* of the domain you want to solve your ODE in, then your solution can be written as a power series $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n}$ (you don't know at this stage what the coefficient $a_n$ are going to be). I believe this is taught to students rather early, no?

---

Let's write the ODE slightly differently

$$
\underbrace{xy''}_A+\underbrace{y'}_{B}-\underbrace{xy'}_{C}+\underbrace{m y}_D=0
$$
with $m$ a positive integer (here $m=1+\lambda$). Insert the power series for $y(x)$. You get
$$
\underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n n(n-1)x^{n-1}}_A
+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n nx^{n-1}}_{B}-\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n x^n}_{C}+\underbrace{m\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n}_D=0
$$
Or upon manipulation and rearranging becomes
$$
m + a_1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big[(n+1)^2a_{n+1}+(m-n)a_n\Big]x^n=0
$$
The condition $y(0)=1$ gives you $a_0=1$. To find the rest of the coefficients, note that a power series is zero if the coefficient of each power is zero. This means
$
a_1=-m$
and
$$
(n+1)^2a_{n+1}=-(m-n)a_n
$$
Now note that eventually (in fact for $n=m$) the right hand side of the above equation vanishes. This results in $a_{m+1}=a_{m+2}=\cdots = 0$. In other words, your solution is a polynomial. More explictly, you have a a recursive relation (for $n\leq m$)
$$
a_n = -\frac{m -n +1}{n^2}a_{n-1}\Longrightarrow
a_n = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(m-1)!}{n!^2(m-n)!}a_1=(-1)^n {m\choose n}\frac{1}{n!}
$$
In other words, putting all of these together the solution is
$$
\boxed{
y(x):=L_m(x) = \sum_{n=0}^m (-1)^n {m\choose n}\frac{x^n}{n!}}
$$
This polynomial, as people mentioned in comments is called *$m$th Laguerre polynomial*, but you are probably not expected to know the name. Finding the above formula should have been enough to get you full credit probably.

Comment: It's a little inconsistent whether this is taught in a first semester course for ODE. Given that the OP was asked this question, it was likely covered, but I have both participated in and taught a class where series solutions were not covered.

Comment: This helps a lot thanks. Apparently we went through one Laguerre problem once during the last week (which I didn't attend). We did not cover series other then that lone example...

Comment: Well, if indeed "not a single student was able to solve it" as you said, then probably many students, like yourself, didn't attend that lecture. Such low attendance might lead to anger and frustration for the instructor. That anger has turned into retaliation in this instance. Could've been worse, just saying :)

Comment: @Hamed you're right on the money about the lectures haha

Comment: @Hamed the professor solved it using a Laplace transform and then using the identity of the binomial theorem.